# Size difference between Maven generated JAR file vs Eclipse export JAR file

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jar

I've noticed something strange while using maven. When exporting my Java project with eclipse and compare the file size with the one generated with maven-jar-plugin or maven-assembly, the last one looks more fat, sometimes, 2 times the size of the first.

Anyone have an idea of this size difference?

Comment: Maybe a different set of dependencies is included? What about the transitive dependencies?

Comment: Unzip the JAR to find out whether it is caused by different ZIP compression levels or by different content (e.g. in the Maven JAR there might be additional files in `META-INF/maven` or by what J Fabian Meier says).

Comment: Yes, after unziping the Jar file, from both build, the maven one come with a lot of additional files when Eclipse exported Jar only include classpath jar without unziping them

Answer (score 1):

`jar tvf thatjar.jar` prints the names and sizes of all files inside. Then just compare the two and you'll know what's going on. Alternatively, just fetch any zip tool, such as [7-zip](https://www.7-zip.org) and open those jar files (at least as far as looking at them / unpacking them is concerned, they are ZIP files. Creating them with non-jar-aware tools is a bit tricky though, don't do that. But looking/reading with zip tools like 7zip works great).

Most likely culprit is that your maven-assembly plugin is striping the deps in, and eclipse isn't.